# Socket.io 2.0.3 on Openshift 2 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, openshift

Im tring to use socket.io 2.0.3 on Openshift 2 with node.js (lasted version) and I can't, when I run on local, the socket work perfect, but In openshift i get this error:

```
GET http://tfg-eliasmarnev.rhcloud.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LtWrbEF net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

And that is the code:

**SERVER**

**app.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); 


//App configuration
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;

//Websockets con socket.io
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Tanto el puerto como la ip son necesarios para OpenShift, 
//de lo contrario intenta enlazar el servidor con la IP 0.0.0.0 y falla
server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
      console.log( "APP Listening on: " + server_ip_address + ":" + server_port )
    }); 

// Permitir que algunos archivos sean enviados a través de HTTP
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/')); 

// Serve GET on http://domain/
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//Iniciamos la conexión.
io.on('connection', function (socket) { // Conexiones entrantes de clientes

    console.log('Usuario conectado');

    //Permanecemos a la escucha del evento coordenada
    socket.on('coordenada', function (data) { // listen to the event

        io.emit('notificacion', { // emit an event to all connected sockets
            Nombre: data.name
        });
    }); 
});
```

**CLIENT**

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**factory.js**

```
app.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

   //var socket = io.connect('http://tfg-eliasmarnev.rhcloud.com:3000/', {'forceNew':true });   
   //var socket = io.connect(); 
     var socket = io.connect('http://tfg-eliasmarnev.rhcloud.com:3000');

  return {
    on: function(eventName, callback){
      socket.on(eventName, callback);
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data);
    }
  };
}]);
```

And i dont know the problem, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be accessing WebSockets over port 8000 per the [v2 documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html)

Comment: I tried that whitout result, moreover my app run on port 3000, its obligatory use the port 8000?

Comment: Your application must use environment variables for the port to listen on, `OPENSHIFT_<cart-name>_PORT`.

Comment: Yes, I using var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000; isn't enough? sorry for my ignorance in this theme..

Comment: No worries =) So with your app running on the correct port (OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT), then *access* the application publicly on port 8000.

The port that your application is listening on, isn't the same port that it's available on publicly.

Comment: To be clear, websockets are accessed over port 8000/8443 (ws://host:8000 or wss://host:8443). And your web application is available over port 80/443 (http://host or https://host).

Comment: Now it works! I have used port 8000 on the client as well: var socket = io.connect('ws://tfg-eliasmarnev.rhcloud.com:8000/', {transports: ['websocket']});  Thanks!!